# Slight voltage drop

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a old phone charge (5v/890ohms)

I want to to wire it into my daughter's night light which require 4.5 volts (3AA batteries)

Can I just use a resistor to drop that .5 v?

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: 890 ohms? You mean mA, right? I would try to drop down the voltage with a diode instead.

Comment: I think it isn't neccessary at all.

Comment: Yes Mathias mA :-)

Comment: As Jasen noted in his now deleted answer, Alkaline cells have an initial terminal voltage of about 1.65V (he suggested 1.7) Either way 3 cells give 4.95 - 5.1V. So no voltage dropper is needed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions.  The reason I said 4.5v is because the night light has a power jack and it has 4.5v printed under it

Answer (score 4):

> I have a old phone charge (5v/890ohms)

This doesn't make sense. Nobody quotes a resistance value for a power supply. It's more likely to be 5 V, 890 mA.

> I want to to wire it into my daughter's night light which require 4.5 volts (3AA batteries)

Three AA alkaline batteries when fresh can give 3 x 1.6 V per cell = 4.8 V total. (See [Duracell Ultra Power AA](http://www.jmargolin.com/furnace/Ultra-Power_AA_MX1500.pdf) datasheet.) If the device can handle this it is probably going to be OK at 5 V.

> Can I just use a resistor to drop that .5 v?

A diode would be better as it will drop about 0.6 V over a range of currents. This avoids the need for any measurements or resistor calculations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCtUsV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Connection with diode.*